# PowerEdge 2800 Server - PERC 4e/Di RAID -- Installing Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, drivers, dell-poweredge

Have the above server (got it for free) with the PERC 4e/Di raid controller inside (according to dell's site).

I've downloaded the drivers to a floppy. The Windows Server 2003 Install disk recognizes the fact these disks exist and that the drivers on the floppy are newer. I select them to load, I see several screen flashes with "Windows is starting..." at the bottom of the screen and then I get the message saying no hard disks could be found.

We've looked inside the machine and there is no IDE or SATA capability to speak of.

Any ideas on what we should do? :)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to build Windows Server 2003 on a PowerEdge 2800 is to use Dell's [Systems Build and Update Utility for the 2800](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R181938&SystemID=PWE_PNT_2800&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=17782&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=248199). Download the ISO, burn it to a CD then boot from it and follow the instructions.

It will gather some key data from you and then drive the W2K3 build for you while ensuring that all the necessary drivers (including the RAID driver for the boot volumes) are included.

Comment: This is how I've installed all my Dell machines and it works great. Make sure you get the latest so it has the latest drivers for the machine you'll work on and the OS that are available.

Comment: That is awesome! I will give it a go. :D

Comment: This works, I asked the same question about the 2950 the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you checked the Dell site using the service tag, it should be the correct controller and drivers. You could also look into updating the firmware on the controller and then trying again.

Answer (score 1):

With dell servers, your best bet is to boot off the [Installation and Server Management CD](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&releaseid=R146318&SystemID=PWE_PNT_2800&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=10655&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=7&catid=36&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=204270) first, that CD has all the drivers you need, and will prep your windows install for you.